# Методы Scanner и проверка

Tags: java

пишу описание к дипломному проекту хотелось бы у вас уточнить правильность моей информации по Java, знаю как работает, а вот описать правильно надо уметь: 
1. `hasNextInt()` — метод проверяет, являются ли данные числом или нет (возвращает `true` или `false`) 
2. `hasNextLine()` — метод проверяет, являются ли данные строкой или нет. (возвращает `true` или `false`)
Если неправильно описал методы, поправьте пожалуйста или если у вас есть более точные и короткие формулировки, то можете их написать пожалуйста, чтобы я смог их использовать, заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятен смысл вопроса, когда уже всё за вас описано [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

**hasNextInt()** - Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method. (Возвращает **true**, если переданное значение может быть распознанно как **int** в десятичной системе исчесления)

**hasNextLine()** - Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. (Возвращает **true**, если передана строка в качестве входного параметра текущего сканнера)

Comment: А как я описал, это правильно?

Comment: Не совсем. Что значит строка? Что является !строка ? 
Проверка, является ли числом. Double/double, int/Integer это всё числа. Про какой идёт речь? **Hex** тоже можно считать числом, только шестнадцатиричным, а бит тоже число.